# Parsing of React components and extracting props values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to find all files with components using a specific component and extract the value of a specific property that is passed to the component.

I can build AST for all files and find the components I need. But how do I read the value of the property? It can be not just a string, but the result of executing a function, for example:

```
<MyComp interestingProp={calcPropValue()} />
```

Is there a way to compute the value based on the AST node for this expression?

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible for pure functions. Just wondering, why do you need this? Some kind of SSR?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov: I need to extract the text labels for each component and store "route - text label" map.

Comment: If you have full access to the code base, why do not you want to do it at runtime with some helper code?

Comment: I want to have static data.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov it's possible with pure functions only if they either don't take params (seems unlikely) or none of the params' values depend on runtime so that they can be obtained from the AST.